# How to read video streaming URL vuforia in iOS

Tags: ios, video-streaming, vuforia

I am experimenting with Vuforia Video Playback sample application in IOS. I wanna add and play the video from a URL. I have tried all the steps but it not plays. How can I do this?. if anyone does this please share with me code 
I have try this , but this is open on new view controller 
Basically you need to look for #ifdef EXAMPLE_CODE_REMOTE_FILE

in the `AppDelegate.mm` file and invoke this by defining the macro above.

Then set your URL as specified:

```
    [player load:@"http://www.kittikoon.name/research/chv.mp4" playImmediately:NO fromPosition:VIDEO_PLAYBACK_CURRENT_POSITION];
```

Comment: please share some code

Comment: Please give me your mail id , i will share with you code

Comment: @matloobHasnain do you have its solution?

Comment: @NishantChandwani did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Yes i have found